# "contribute to investigating" or "contribute to investigate"

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to find, which of the following sentences is correct?

> A) We try to highlight how they contribute **to investigate** their importance.
>
> B) We try to highlight how they contribute **to investigating** their importance.

I found that both cases were used frequently in formal writing.

Edited:

Sources for each case:

For A: "Their multifaceted nature means that there are very
many routes **to investigating** their importance for understanding social change" in "A lineage for contemporary inter-city studies" book.

B: "More factors are analysed **to investigate** their importance in scoring from shots and shot probabilities" in "Applications of logistic regression to shots at goal at association football" book.

Comment: Cite your sources and research done so far please. One of those examples is *very* ungrammatical.

Comment: They mean different things.

Comment: @RMac I added sources.

Comment: Your new examples make sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , Beside them, could you plz tell me which one is "more" correct and why?

Comment: They mean different things!!  Are they contributing to the investigation, or is it their contributions you wish to investigate???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misanalysing your "sources".

*Contribute* normally takes "to" plus a noun phrase, or something which can act as a noun phrase; hence *contribute to investigating*. *Contribute to investigate* is not grammatical.

Similarly *routes to investigating*.

But *More factors are analysed to investigate...* is an entirely different construction. *Analyse* doesn't take a "to" phrase, so *to investigate* is something different. In fact, it is a "purpose" clause - infinitive with "to" often has the meaning "in order to ...".